# Is this an example of an morphism in the category of pointed sets?

Tags: category-theory, definition

Let $S = (\{1,4,5,9,14,19,24\}, 19)$.

Let $T = (\{1,4,5,9,14,19,24\}, 1)$.

Define the morphism $f: S \to T$ as follows:

$$   
    f(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        n , & \text{when } n \notin \{1,19\} \\
        1 , & \text{when } n = 19 \\
        19, & \text{when } n = 1
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$

I think it is but I suspect that there is a better way of expressing $f$ using more 'category-centric ' notation. It isn't an automorphism, but does it have a name?

Comment: Yes, this is a morphism, and an isomorphism too!

Comment: @hunter The carrier set is the same so I thought there might be terminology to describe isomorphisms on a fixed carrier set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be?

In the category of pointed sets morphisms are simply functions $f: (X,x) \to (Y,y)$ where $f :X \to Y$ and $f(x) = y$. Your function is well defined and maps $x$ to $y$ indeed. Moreover, your morphism is a bijection and hence it is an isomorphism. Note that if $x \neq y$ then the objects $(X,x)$, $(X,y)$ are not equal. In fact you've shown they're isomorphic, though.

Comment: So just write: $\quad$ Let $f: (X,x) \to (X,y)$ be an isomorphism..." Sounds like a dumb question now, but the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set left me a bit uncertain.

Comment: @CopyPasteIt sorry I don't understand if you're asking a follow up question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am accepting your answer now- there is no special terminology when you have an ismorphism on a fixed carrier set $X$.  I thought of *sautaomorphism* but that would be silly! thanks!